Ubuntu doesn’t boot after upgrade
I’ve recently updated the OS from 22.04 to 24.04 and many problems occurred. First of all I was connected to WiFi but nothing could load, and then I could not launch any application. After rebooting the system, the following boot screen appeared. Do you have any solution to this problem?


the root file system is mounted as read-only. boot with the recovery mood.

I have booted with the recovery mode, I tried to update the grub menu. I also tried boot repair with a live USB Ubuntu stick. Still the same, Ubuntu does not boot.

check the /etc/fstab

Everything is fine with /etc/fstab.

use this command in the recovery mood: dpkg --configure -a

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1523063/1698042
